# Teradata error 6706 loading non printable characters

Tags: unix, encoding, ascii, teradata, plaintext

I have an ETL that creates a plain text that later will be loaded into Teradata, in the source data there is a column UTF8 enconded that has all kind of characters including non printable, I properly write the file but i get **Error Code 6706**: The string contains an untranslatable character.

This is the destiny column

```
column VARCHAR(300) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC
```

I can load characters like this **é** but not characters like this **’**

How can I properly write the file, and validate before sending the data, I don't have access to the data base just know that they get the error Code 6706.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @dnoeth...i guess making column as unicode will also work...

Comment: @anwaar_hell:  Of course, this is what i wanted to write, damn cut&paste&forget to modify.

Comment: @dnoeth...you rarely make mistakes...:)

Comment: @anwaar_hell: More than you imagine :)

Comment: @dnoeth I can't change the data base, my ETL provides the data and i have to figure out how to send in a way they can load the data

Comment: Tell the owner of the database that Unicode data can't be stored in a Latin column (well, you can store it, but then it's garbage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make column as unicode...

```
column VARCHAR(300) CHARACTER SET unicode NOT CASESPECIFIC.
```

Comment: I can't change the data base, my ETL provides the data and i have to figure out how to send in a way they can load the data